# Get length of text in QML label in pixels

Tags: qml, qt5

Is it somehow possible to get length of text label in QML in pixels?

like if

```
Label {
    id: label1
    text: "123"
}
```

How to get length *in pixels* for "123"?

Comment: Of just the text part of it (`TextMetrics`), or of the entire Label object? (`width` and `implicitWidth` come to mind).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe label1.paintedWidth is what you're looking for.